# Scanner.nextDouble(): reading double with "."

Tags: java

I'm have a little problem with the Java class Scanner:
I need to read a file (.dat) that contains Double values, but it seems like the method Scanner.nextDouble only recognize number written like this: 1234,5678 , with a "," but not with a ".". I wanted to know if there was a way to change that, because the file is generated by another software, so I can't make it change the "," for a ".".

Thanks
Robin

Comment: Replace the `,`'s with `.`'s in your parser, or in the file itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your default `Locale` uses a comma-based decimal separator for `double` values. Try using

```
scanner.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace , with .

Example:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("myNumbers"));
while (sc.hasNext()) {
     String s = sc.next();
     Double d = (Double)s.replace(",",".");
}
```